# Saving iterating destination images from cvCvtColor() function. Source is 8Bit Bayer. Destination can be 8bit Gray/RGB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I have a sequence of images being generated but I need to work a way out to save the images from the `cvCvtColor()` function.

I am passing in a pointer to the function. However, i have the destination array initialized prior and expect it to be updated after the conversion.

I have the output file saved but not with an updated version, instead with all `NULL` values.

```
inline void CCameraStopLineDetection_Task::convert8BitToRGBImage(unsigned char* src8Bit, 
unsigned char*  dst8Bit, unsigned short  imgWidth, unsigned short  imgHeight)
     {
       unsigned char* src = src8Bit; 
       unsigned char* dest = dst8Bit; 
         for (int i = 0; i < imgWidth * imgHeight; ++i) 
          {
                cvCvtColor(src, dest, CV_BayerGR2GRAY);
            *dest++ = (unsigned char)src;
            src++;
         }
     }
```

Any breakthrough will be helpful.

Comment: cvCvtColor takes whole images, not pixels. (also, why are you using the deprecated c-api?)

Comment: I have the associated applications with similar framework and cannot use the lastest version. And yes, I have a code in C++ which does the modification at pixel level. But I intend to use something with openCV. Any suggestions how I can work around in OpenCV for pixel level modification?

Comment: roll your own [then](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor)

Comment: Thanks Berak, I finally had to use the C++ code for pixel level modifications.